# Why I did not got values when I send it to app.post url in json format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

when I try to add data to an *array* using api and json with express app.post method I got an empty values added to my *array* .
I have checked the code many times and tried to add values directly instead of `req.body` methode and it works . 
but when I use `req.body` it does not return any values from *Json* that I have posted to the *URL*.

Here is my index page code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const person = [
    { id: 1, name: 'name1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'name2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'name2' }
];

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello');
});
app.get('/api/person', (req, res) => {
    res.send(person)
});

app.post('/api/person', (req, res) => {

    const per = {
        id: req.body.id,
        name: req.body.name
    };
    person.push(per);
});

/*app.post();
app.put();
app.delete();*/


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`connecting on  ${port}`);
})
```

I send data from the postman tool

like this

```
{
"id":44,
"name":"name44"
}
```

and in output I got this result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQsCb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postman, where you enter the raw body, make sure it is set to Json and not Text.
This way when you send it will add the header *Content-Type: application/json*.

Comment: I send it via Tests zone in Json forma and I got undefined values

Comment: thanks I found the problem it was exactly what you mention , I didn't choose json at body

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post('/api/person', (req, res) => {
    const per = {
        id: req.body.id,
        name: req.body.name
    }
    person.push(per)
    return res.json({ person })
})
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25766813)